# Finding an isometry given the distance between points

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

If $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $d(A,B)=d(C,D)$, then exists an isometry $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, such that $f(A)=C, f(B)=D$.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some context, as well as a description of your efforts to solve the problem?

Comment: You're going to have to rotate, then translate.  It's often easier to solve the more concrete problem first:  construct a map $g_{C, D}$ sending $(0, 0, \ldots, 0) \mapsto C$ and $(1, 0, \ldots, 0) \mapsto D$.  Then, $f = g_{C, D} \circ g_{A,B}^{-1}$.

Comment: You might also like to consider a glide reflection where the reflection is done along a plane which bisects the angle created by the lines $AB$ and $CD$. If those lines are parallel then reflect in the plane which is equidistant from both lines. You may need to do another reflection along a plane perpendicular to $CD$ if the orientation is incorrect.